# Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\mathbb N$ and convergence

Tags: general-topology

In $\beta\mathbb N$ there are no non-trivial convergent sequences. I want to show this, but what is the meaning of non -trivial convergent sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Any sequence which is eventually constant converges (in any topology). These might be called the "trivial convergent sequences."

Comment: could you give me example for non-trivial convergent squence? and trivial convergence?

Comment: Do you mean unique limit for sequence?

Comment: @ege: No, Qiaochu is not talking about unique limits. The sequence $\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ is an example of a non-trivial convergent sequence in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. The sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $x_n=n$ if $n<100$ and $x_n=-1$ if $n\ge 100$ is a trivial convergent sequence: it’s eventually constant at $-1$, so of course it **has** to converge to $-1$ no matter what topology on $\Bbb R$ is considered.

Comment: Oh, yes, I can see. Thanks so much .